# Getting listbox from another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I want to get the selected item from another from to display on a textbox.

I have two forms. `MainForm` and `FoodRegisterForm`. In `Mainform` there is a listbox of different animals and in `FoodRegisterForm` there is a textbox.

When the user selects an item on the `Mainform` listbox I want the selected item to be displayed on the textbox on `RegisterForm`.

Here is how I tried it:

```
public partial class FoodRegister : Form
    {
        private MainForm mainform;
        public FoodRegister() 
        {
            mainform = new MainForm();
            InitializeComponent();
            mainform.Show();

        }

        private void Nametxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Nametxt.Text  = mainform. //Don't know how to go from here

        }

    }
```

The listbox that I'm trying to get is named `Animallst`
The problem is that I don't know how to get the `Animallst` from `mainForm` to `FoodregisterForm`

**Update:**

Here is `MainForm`:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {   ///<summary> Instance of AnimalManager </summary>
        private AnimalManager animalmgr = null;
        private FoodSchedule m_foodManager = new FoodSchedule();
        private RecipeManager m_recipeManager = new RecipeManager();

        public MainForm()
        {
            //Visual Studio initializations
            InitializeComponent();

            //My initializations
            InitializeGUI();
            ///<summary> Fills the combobox with the values of the Enums </summary> 
            Gendercmb.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GenderType));
            Categorylst.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Categorytype));
            animalmgr = new AnimalManager();
        }

        private void InitializeGUI()
        {
        }

        //public string GetListBoxSelectedItem()
        //{
        //    if (Animallst.SelectedItem != null)
        //        return Animallst.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //    return string.Empty;
        //}


        /// <summary>
        /// Read inputs from the user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Animal"></param>
        private void ReadInput(Animal animal)
        {
            //Reads name
            animal.Name = ReadName();
            //Reads age
            animal.Age = ReadAge();
            //Reads gender
            animal.Gender = this.Gendercmb.GetItemText(this.Gendercmb.SelectedItem);

            //Reads teeth
            Mammal mammal = animal as Mammal;
            if (mammal != null)
            {
                mammal.Teeth = ReadTeeth();

            }
            //Reads barklevel
            Dog dog = animal as Dog;
            if (dog != null)
            {
                dog.BarkLevel = ReadBarklevel();

            }
            //Reads jumplevel
            Cat cat = animal as Cat;
            if (cat != null)
            {
                cat.Jumplevel = ReadJumpLevel();
            }
            //Reads toxicity
            Snake snake = animal as Snake;
            if (snake != null)
            {
                snake.ToxicLevel = ReadToxicity();
            }
            //Reads camouflage
            Lizard lizard = animal as Lizard;
            if (lizard != null)
            {
                lizard.CamouflageLevel = ReadCamouflage();
            }
            //Reads tail
            Reptile reptile = animal as Reptile;
            if (reptile != null)
            {
                reptile.TailLenght = ReadTail();

            }

        }
        ///<summary> 
        ///Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them 
        ///</summary>
        private int ReadAge()
        {
            int age = 0;

            int.TryParse(Agetxt.Text, out age);

            return age;
        }
        ///<summary> Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them </summary>
        private int ReadBarklevel()
        {
            int bark = 0;

            int.TryParse(barktxt.Text, out bark);

            return bark;

        }
        ///<summary> Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them </summary>
        private int ReadJumpLevel()
        {
            int jump = 0;

            int.TryParse(jumptxt.Text, out jump);

            return jump;
        }
        ///<summary> Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them </summary>
        private int ReadToxicity()
        {
            int Toxicity = 0;

            int.TryParse(Toxicitytxt.Text, out Toxicity);

            return Toxicity;
        }
        ///<summary> Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them </summary>
        private int ReadCamouflage()
        {
            int Camouflage;

            int.TryParse(Camouflagetxt.Text, out Camouflage);

            return Camouflage;
        }
        ///<summary> Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them </summary>
        private int ReadTeeth()
        {
            int teeth = 0;

            int.TryParse(teethtxt.Text, out teeth);

            return teeth;
        }
        ///<summary> Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them </summary>
        private string ReadName()
        {
            string name = "";
            name = Nametxt.Text;
            return name;
        }
        ///<summary> Assigns the textfield to local variables and returns them </summary>
        private int ReadTail()
        {
            int tail = 0;

            int.TryParse(tailtxt.Text, out tail);

            return tail;
        }

        //--
        /// <summary>
        /// Add mammals animals if mammal is selected
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns="Either Dog or Cat"></returns>
        private Mammal addMammal()
        {
            Mammal result; //variable

            switch ((MammalType)Animallst.SelectedIndex)
            {  //result is dog
                case MammalType.Dog:
                    {

                        result = new Dog();
                        break;
                    }
                //result is cat
                case MammalType.Cat:
                    {
                        result = new Cat();
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    throw new Exception("Animal type not found.");
            }

            ReadInput(result); //read inputs

            return result; //returns the result
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Add Reptile animals if reptile is selected
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns="Either Snake or reptile"></returns>
        private Reptile AddReptile()
        {
            Reptile result;

            switch ((ReptileType)Animallst.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case ReptileType.Snake:
                    {
                        result = new Snake();
                        break;
                    }
                case ReptileType.Lizard:
                    {
                        result = new Lizard();
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    throw new Exception("Animal type not found.");
            }

            ReadInput(result);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When user clicks "Add to list"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Resultlst.ClearSelected();
            switch ((Categorytype)Categorylst.SelectedIndex)
            {//if Mammal is selected - Adds the mammal animal selected from above.
                case Categorytype.Mammal:
                    {
                        Mammal mammal = addMammal();
                        animalmgr.Add(mammal);
                        break;
                    }

                //Same but for Reptile animals
                case Categorytype.Reptile:
                    {
                        Reptile m_reptile = AddReptile();
                        animalmgr.Add(m_reptile);
                        break;
                    }


            }
            UpdateResults();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uppdates the list
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateResults()
        {
            Resultlst.Items.Clear();  //Erase current list
            //Get one elemnet at a time from manager, and call its 
            //ToString method for info - send to listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < animalmgr.Count; index++)
            {
                Animal animal = animalmgr.GetAt(index);

                //Adds to the list.
                Resultlst.Items.Add(animal);

                Resultlst.DisplayMember = "Description";

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the FoodSchedule
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateFoodSchedule()
        {
            //Gets Eater type of selected animal
            Animal theanimal = (Animal)Resultlst.SelectedItem;
            if (Resultlst.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            string eater = "";
            if(theanimal.GetEaterType() == EaterType.Carnivore)
            {
                eater = "Meat eater";
            }
            else if (theanimal.GetEaterType() == EaterType.Herbivore)
            {
                eater = "Plant eater";
            }

            else if (theanimal.GetEaterType() == EaterType.Omnivorous)
            {
                eater = "All eater";
            }


            EaterTypetxt.Text = eater;

            //Gets Food schedule of selected animal

            FoodSchedule animal = theanimal.GetFoodSchedule();

            //Adds to the list.
            foodlst.DataSource = animal.FoodDescriptionList;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the UppdateSchedule to this event handeler so
        /// that the FoodSchedule updates when an item on the list is selected.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Resultlst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateFoodSchedule();
        }

        private void foodbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FoodRegister foodForm = new FoodRegister();
            foodForm.Show();
        }

        private void staffbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StaffForm staffForm = new StaffForm();
            staffForm.Show();
        }

        private void deletebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Delete();
            UpdateResults();
        }
        private void Delete()
        {
            animalmgr.DeleteAt(Resultlst.SelectedIndex);
        }



        }
```

Comment: can post main form code?

Comment: please post all relevant code that of which pertains to your question.. also in your code where you are wanting to assign `Nametxt.Text = mainform` you need to go one level deeper depending of the scope and do something like  `Nametxt.Text = mainform.listbox.SelectItem` for example but can't tell without seeing the code in the MainForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this. It might work.

```
public string GetListBoxSelectedItem()

    {
        if(yourListBox.SelectedItem != null)
            return yourListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

FoodRegister class:

```
 private void Nametxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

     {
         Nametxt.Text  = mainform.GetListBoxSelectedItem()
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a contructor in `MainForm` that allows you to pass your `FoodRegister` form into it.

For example:

**MainForm**

```
private FoodRegister foodReg { get; set; }

public MainForm(FoodRegister reg)
{
   foodReg = reg;
}

private Animallst_onSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   foodReg.Nametxt.Text = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

**FoodRegister**

```
    public FoodRegister() 
    {
        mainform = new MainForm(this);
        InitializeComponent();
        mainform.Show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your mainform add a method:

```
public string GetListBoxSelectedItem()
{
    if(yourListBox.SelectedItem != null)
        return yourListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    return string.Empty;
}
```

and in the FoodRegister:

```
 private void Nametxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Nametxt.Text  = mainform.GetListBoxSelectedItem()
 }
```